# Tate curve and action of inertia group

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, galois-representations

I read the answers to this question [Clarifying a comment of Serre](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170987/clarifying-a-comment-of-serre). However I miss a passage of the second answer and since I can't comment there I have should post a new question.

I don't understand the following passage

Why the action of the inertial subgroup is trivial over $\mu_{\ell}$ whenever $v \nmid \ell$?

Comment: Do you know where the number field $\mathbb Q(\zeta_\ell)$ is ramified?

Comment: Yes only in $\ell$, since the inertia subgroup has cardinality equal to the ramification index then can be only the identity over the other prime. Is this right?

Comment: Well the argument isn't right, but you are right about it being ramified only in $\ell$. From this can you deduce something about the action of Galois on $\mu_\ell$?

Comment: BTW your question will have more chance of being answered if you ask only one question per post. Otherwise it's more work for people to answer.

Comment: You are right about the number of question but I would not annoying people with too much post. For your second hint, I know that the Galois acts permuting the element of $\mu_{\ell}$  but don't think  this is the point.

Answer (score 0):

First, a quick summary of splitting of primes in Galois extensions (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Splitting_of_prime_ideals_in_Galois_extensions), or Marcus' *Number Fields* for more on this topic). Suppose that $L$ is a finite Galois extension of $\mathbb{Q}$, and let $p$ be a rational prime. Let $\mathcal{O}_L$ be the ring of integers of $L$. Then,
$$p\mathcal{O}_L = (\wp_1\cdots\wp_r)^e$$
where $\wp_i$ are the prime ideals of $\mathcal{O}_L$ lying above $p$, and $r,e\geq 1$ are integers, and $e$ is called the ramification index. The degree of the extension of finite fields $[\mathcal{O}_L/\wp_i : \mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}]$ does not depend on $i$, and we call it $f$. Now let $G=\operatorname{Gal}(L/\mathbb{Q})$ be the Galois group of the extension, fix $1\leq i\leq r$, let $\wp=\wp_i$, and let $D_\wp$ and $I_\wp$ be, respectively, the decomposition group and inertia subgroups of $G$ attached to the prime $\wp$. The size of $I_\wp$ is $e$, and the size of $D_\wp$ is $ef$. There is an inclusion of fields
$$\mathbb{Q} \subseteq L^{D_\wp} \subseteq L^{I_\wp} \subseteq L$$
where $L^H$ is the subfield of $L$ fixed by a subgroup $H$ of $G$. In particular, $[L:L^{I_\wp}]=e$.

Thus, $p$ ramifies in $L/\mathbb{Q}$ if and only if $e=1$, if and only if $I_\wp$ is trivial, if and only if $L^{I_\wp}=L$, if and only if $I_\wp$ acts trivially on all of $L$.

In your case, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell)$, where $\ell$ is a prime different from $p$. Since only $\ell$ is ramified in $L/\mathbb{Q}$, it follows that $I_\wp$ acts trivially on $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_\ell)$, for any prime ideal $\wp$ above $p\neq \ell$.